# Visual Studio 2008: How do I save all the breakpoints set?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm looking for a way to save all the breakpoints I've set for future reference. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2010 you can [import and export breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293657.aspx), if you are on any version except the express (though the C++ express version also has this feature).

In VS 2008 You may be able to get similar functionality using VBA, but I don't know for certain.

[Here](https://intuitlabs.com/experiments/breakpoint-analyzer-microsoft-visual-studio) is a free addon to visual studio that will save breakpoints to file.